# "Why does the if statement stop working?"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have created a data entry Useform. I have loop that will update the spreadsheet.

Example

```
For i = 2 to 10
 if {condition} then
     sheet.Cells(i,2) = txtbox1.value
     sheet.Cells(i,3) = txtbox1.value
     sheet.Cells(i,4) = txtbox1.value
```

When i is 2 or 3 and the condition is met the statements are executed but if i is 4 or higher and meets the condition the statements are not executed.  Do you why this will happened?

```
Sub Update()
Dim sh As Worksheet, iRow As Long, i As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

iRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To iRow

     If sh.Cells(i, 22).Value = frmForm.TxtLookup.Text Then
 
       sh.Cells(i, 2) = frmForm.TxtTruck.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 3) = frmForm.CmbVendor.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 4) = frmForm.TxtPO.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 5) = frmForm.TxtBOL.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 6) = frmForm.CmbCarrier.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 7) = frmForm.TxtPallet.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 8) = IIf(frmForm.OptNo.Value = True, "No", "Yes")
       sh.Cells(i, 9) = frmForm.TxtTemp.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 10) = frmForm.TxtEmployee.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 11) = frmForm.TxtGuardTime.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 12) = frmForm.TxtDockTime.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 13) = frmForm.TxtStartTime.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 14) = frmForm.TxtEndTime.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 15) = frmForm.TxtRcvStart.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 16) = frmForm.TxtRcvComplete.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 17) = frmForm.TxtReceiver.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 18) = frmForm.CmbBio.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 19) = frmForm.CmbCage.Value
       sh.Cells(i, 20) = IIf(frmForm.CmbBio.Value = "All", frmForm.TxtPallet.Value,  IIf(frmForm.CmbBio.Value = "", 0, frmForm.CmbBio.Value))
       sh.Cells(i, 21) = IIf(frmForm.CmbCage.Value = "All", frmForm.TxtPallet.Value, IIf(frmForm.CmbCage.Value = "", 0, frmForm.CmbCage.Value))

   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint to make sure the iRow value is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Or `Debug.Print iRow` before the loop.

Comment: If the statements inside the `If` block are not executed, the most likely reason is that the `If` condition was *not* met.

Comment: Adding to @TimWilliams, in your statement `If sh.Cells(i, 22).Value = frmForm.TxtLookup.Text Then`, add a simple `Else` statement like `Debug.Print "If condition not met", sh.Cells(i, 22).Value, frmForm.TxtLookup.Text` to show when the values are not equal.

Comment: What are the types of data you're dealng with both in the column and the textbox?  Does the type change at row 4+ ??